# Getting same memory address for NSStrings assigned from string literals

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm getting same memory address for the below code snippet

```
NSString *str = @"2";

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", str, @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", nil];

NSString *strTest = @"6";
strTest = @"2";
NSLog(@"object  %x", [arr objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Object "str", "strTest" and the "log print" giving same address though I've declared different instance for `NSString` then how is it happening. Please someone let me know. It is getting strange for me.

Answer (score 5):

`str` and the `NSLog` should provide the same memory address, since it's the same object and no new allocation is made. The two lines of the `strTest` variable are probably being optimized by the compiler to a single `NSString *strTest = @"2"`, and since `NSString` is immutable there's no problem with saving the memory space and pointing it to the same `@"2"` string that is allocated in the data segment of your executable.

Comment: The poster can see what is happening here by printing the address of `str` and `strTest`.  `NSLog(@"Address of str: %x, and of strTest: %x", &str, &strTest)` will show two different locations, but their values will be the same.

Comment: It is fine "str" and "log" print will give the same address but if "str" and "strTest" are using the same memory address then what will happen to "strTest" if I change the "str" both will get change?

Comment: `str` and `strTest` are pointers, you should pass themselves and not their address (which will give you a memory address on the stack.

Comment: Since `str` and `strTest` are immutable, you can't just change `str`. To change it you'll have to set a new value for it, and that will change `str` to point to a new memory location.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with that as they are string literals. You do have two different addresses for str and strTest. They just happen to rerfer to the same object, wich is a string literal. You have NOT created two separate instances of them.

Try

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @"2"]; 
strTest = [NSSTring stringWithString:str];
```

or so.
However, if you still do

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", str, @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", nil];
```

and then

```
NSLog(@"object  %x", [arr objectAtIndex:1]);
```

you will see that the Object with Index 1 in `arr` and the object to which `str` refers are one identical intance simply because they are and they are supposed to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

String literals like @"2" are never released and they point to the same memory which means that pointer comparison is true and they share the same address.